# How to Iterate through cur.fetchall() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on database connectivity in Python 3.4.
There are two columns in my database.

Below is the query which gives me all the data from two columns in shown format
QUERY:

```
cur.execute(""" select * from filehash """)
data=cur.fetchall()
print(data)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('F:\\test1.py', '12345abc'), ('F:\\test2.py', 'avcr123')]
```

To iterate through this output, my code is as below

```
cur.execute(""" select * from filehash """)
data=cur.fetchall()

i=0
j=1

for i,row in data:
    print(row[i])
    print(row[j])
    i=i+1
```

This gives me below error

```
print(row[i])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Let me know how can we work on individual values of `fetchall()`

Comment: @ Redbeard011010 repzero zvone

I can idivudally access like row[0], row[1]

but when I loop it using 

for i,j in data:
    print(data[i])
    print(data[j])

I am getting below error

 print(data[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

same for enumerate(data) as well

Comment: @ Redbeard011010 repzero zvone

I can idivudally access like row[0], row[1]

but when I loop it using 

for i,j in data:
    print(data[i])
    print(data[j])

I am getting below error

 print(data[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

same for enumerate(data) as well

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have two colunms in the table, so each row will contain two elements.

It is easiest to iterate through them this way:

```
for column1, column2 in data:
```

That is the same as:

```
for row in data:
    column1, column2 = row
```

You could also, as you tried:

```
for row in data:
    print row[0] # or row[i]
    print row[1] # or row[j]
```

But that failed because you overwrote `i` with the value of first column, in this line: `for i, row in data:`.

**EDIT**

BTW, in general, you will never *need* this pattern in Python:

```
i = 0
for ...:
    ...
    i += 1
```

Instead of that, it is common to do simply:

```
for item in container:
    # use item

# or, if you really need i:
for i, item in enumerate(container):
    # use i and item
```

Comment: @ Redbeard011010 repzero zvone

I can idivudally access like row[0], row[1]

but when I loop it using 

for i,j in data:
    print(data[i])
    print(data[j])

I am getting below error

 print(data[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

same for enumerate(data) as well

Comment: @npormambi You are now doing worse than in the question ;) npormambi explained well in his answer, but once again from a different angle: `data[7]` is 8th row; `data[7][1]` is 2nd column in 8th row; `for x in data` takes row by row from data and puts it in x, so you can access `x[0]` and `x[1]` to get columns; `for x, y in data` reads row by row from data, unpacks it and puts columns in `x`and `y`. It is cruicial that you understand that part perfectly. Now, **your error**: after `for i, j in data`, column data is written to `i` and `j`, they are no longer 0 and 1, so `data[i]` is just wrong.

Comment: @npormambi To get a better understanding of this, try printing everything: `print (data)`, `print (row)`, `print (i)`, `print (j)` in different places, especially in the line before the error.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over and print rows from `cursor.fetchall()` you'll just want to do:

```
for row in data:
    print row
```

You should also be able to access indices of the row, such as `row[0]`, `row[1]`, iirc.

Of course, instead of printing the row, you can manipulate that row's data however you need.  Imagine the cursor as a set of rows/records (that's pretty much all it is).

Answer (score 1):

looking at

```
[('F:\\test1.py', '12345abc'), ('F:\\test2.py', 'avcr123')]
  i              j                 i            j
```

you are taking a strings i and j and indexing it  like

```
   print(row['F:\\test1.py'])
    print(row['12345abc'])
```

which gave you typeError

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

this is because i in data is a string and your a indexing this

try this

```
for i,j in data:
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

Comment: Hello repzero,

I tried the link shown by you still not working
using Mysql database...

Comment: have you remove  your variables "j=1" and "i=0" and "i=i+1" from your codes and does your data variables contains "[('F:\\test1.py', '12345abc'), ('F:\\test2.py', 'avcr123')]"? ....print(data) to verify this is the true value

Answer (score 0):

As the output you given `[('F:\\test1.py', '12345abc'), ('F:\\test2.py', 'avcr123')]`

```
for i, row in data:
    print(i)  # i is column1's value
    print(row)# row is column's value
```

So you don't need row[i] or row[j], that was wrong, in that each step of that iteration

```
for i, row in data
```

is the same as `i, row = ('abc', 'def')` it set `abc` to variable `i` and 'def' to `row`

BTW ,I don't know what database you use, if you use `Mysql` and python driver`MySQL Connector`, you can checkout this guide to [fetch mysql result as dictionary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html)
you can get a dict in iteration, and the keys is your table fields' name. I think this method is convenient more.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through this:
[('F:\test1.py', '12345abc'), ('F:\test2.py', 'avcr123')]

```
Code:
for i in data:
   print i[0] + '\t' + i[1]
```

Output:

> F:\test1.py     12345abc
>   F:\test2.py     avcr123