# How to fetch all columns from table and save it in s3 as csv file using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

```
cur = con.cursor()
for i in sample:
    cur.execute("select `count(*)`,cricking_duels_ratings,cast(`sysdate()` as CHAR) from {}".format(i))
    res = cur.fetchall()
    for row in res:
        print(row)
    ob = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, '/testing.csv')
    ob.put(Body=row)
    print("done")
```

when I try the above, i'm getting following error

> 'invalid type of parameter body..type: , valid types:
>   , , file-like object'

any suggestions please..

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for [datafreeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808952/flask-nginx-and-uwsgi)

Comment: Did you get an answer? also looking for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normally easier to create a local file, then use `upload_file()` to copy the file to S3. This also makes it easier to debug, since you can view the content of the local file to ensure that it was correctly converted to CSV.

I suspect your problem has to do with converting the `row` into a string containing comma-separated values. See: [How to Iterate through cur.fetchall() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463947/174777)